# Firebase auth custom claims causes issues with loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack, firebase-admin

I am trying to use a boilerplate from a tutorial. I want to apply custom claims in Firebase. This is how my firebase file was set up after the tutorial:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


const config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const database = firebase.database();

const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

export { firebase, googleAuthProvider, database as default };
```

This works, but I can't apply custom claims. When I change the file so it looks like this:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const serviceAccount = require('./service-account-file.json')

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
});

const database = admin.database();

const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

export { admin, googleAuthProvider, database as default };
```

It can't compile. This is my webpack:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    }]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

I applied the custom claims to the database by making a basic project and using the info from firebase. These are the kinds of errors I receive:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js 20:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential'
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js 21:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js
Module parse failed: /Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js Unexpected token (347:40)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|             libraryHeader.libVersion += ' fire/' + settings.firebaseVersion;
|         }
|         this.validateAndApplySettings({ ...settings, ...libraryHeader });
|         const retryConfig = serviceConfig.retry_params.default;
|         this._backoffSettings = {
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js 311:28-62
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@firebase/app' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js 5:15-39
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.js
Module parse failed: /Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.js Unexpected token (1957:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|             const credential = `${client_email}/${todayISO}/auto/storage/goog4_request`;
|             fields = {
|                 ...fields,
|                 bucket: this.bucket.name,
|                 key: this.name,
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js 20:13-30
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src'
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js 22:11-24
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/signer.js
Module parse failed: /Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/signer.js Unexpected token (150:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|                 'X-Goog-Expires': expiresPeriodInSeconds.toString(10),
|                 'X-Goog-SignedHeaders': signedHeaders,
|                 ...(config.queryParams || {}),
|             };
|             // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js 33:17-36
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/p-limit/index.js
Module parse failed: /Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/p-limit/index.js Unexpected token (30:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       try {
|           await result;
|       } catch {}
|
|       next();
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js 25:15-33
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js
Module parse failed: /Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js Unexpected token (37:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     const options = {
|         method: reqOpts.method || 'GET',
|         ...(reqOpts.timeout && { timeout: reqOpts.timeout }),
|         ...(typeof reqOpts.gzip === 'boolean' && { compress: reqOpts.gzip }),
|     };
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js 25:24-48
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtaccess.js
Module parse failed: /Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtaccess.js Unexpected token (83:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         }
|         const header = this.keyId
|             ? { ...DEFAULT_HEADER, kid: this.keyId }
|             : DEFAULT_HEADER;
|         const payload = Object.assign(defaultClaims, additionalClaims);
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js 27:18-45
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth'
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js 17:24-48
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth'
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js 18:11-24
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js
Module parse failed: /Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js Unexpected token (102:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| async function fastFailMetadataRequest(options) {
|     const secondaryOptions = {
|         ...options,
|         url: options.url.replace(getBaseUrl(), getBaseUrl(exports.SECONDARY_HOST_ADDRESS)),
|     };
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/computeclient.js 18:20-43
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/gtoken/build/src'
 @ ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js 10:11-24
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/request/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/retry-request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/forever-agent'
 @ ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js 6:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/retry-request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/forever-agent'
 @ ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js 7:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/retry-request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
 @ ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js 3:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/tunnel.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/retry-request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
 @ ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js 4:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/tunnel.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/retry-request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 32:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/cookies.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/retry-request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src'
 @ ./node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src/index.js 10:11-24
 @ ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js 15:30-44
 @ ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js
 @ ./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/transporters.js
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/Users/josephinegeoghegan/Desktop/Jo/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js 16:30-44
 @ ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js
 @ ./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/transporters.js
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/channel.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/firebase/firebase.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js
```

Please point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: On Stack Overflow, do not show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question and forma it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#setcustomuserclaims

Comment: @Harkal, I really appreciate your answer but I'm not sure how to apply it in my code. I've been trying for quite a long time. Could you please elaborate a little on why I would need to use this? Thanks so much

Comment: @JosephineAnn you r mixing two things. the fireabse-admin-sdk is not used in the client instead in the server and i dont see any logic in using webpack beacause the firebase cli takes care of everythin you just have to fo `firebase init functions` and start writing your functions.

Comment: if you look at the error it says firebase-admin-sdk cant find `fs` which is a server side package ie. it is not supported in the browser so don't mix your client side code with admin side code

Answer (score 0):

As shown here :

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Y're trying to use both sdk client and sdk server in the same environnement, that can be a risk about your app security.

But you can use the cloud fonction to acheive some admin roles :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/